# Android Application database(sqlite) backup on server

Tags: android, sqlite

i used sqlite for creating database. Now i want to take backup of a database file on my server.

so how to upload my sqlite database file to server from my application in android?

Answer (score 0):

Use `getDatabasePath()` to get a `File` object pointing to your database. Then, after you have closed all open `SQLiteOpenHelper` and `SQLiteDatabase` objects, you can upload your database using `HttpUrlConnection`, `HttpClient`, etc.